# How to filter ng-repeat values based on another input ng-model value in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

repeat values based on another input ng-model value in angularjs?

- I have one input value like `Social Psychology` for this value `ng-model is kpcategory`
- I have used ng-repeat like `ng-repeat="question in questions` to list out the all `category` and `name`.
- I tried to filter `Social Psychology` category in `ng-repeat` list, so i used like `ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:kpcategory"`.
- what the issue is, it's filtering `Social Psychology` data's perfectly. but i would like to filter only the category value of `Social Psychology` not for all data's. the issue is  it's filtered includes of `category and category_two`data's.

**Expecting result is:-**

- just want to filter by `catgory` `Social Psychology` so result should be `Social Psychology , John` data.
- [My Plunker For Reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfpwhjvGQrQUSQpbMi5m?p=preview)
- we don't how to solve this issue please help us thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following to filter items by category property only

```
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:{ category: kpcategory }">
      <ul>
          <li><span>{{question.category}} , {{question.name}}</span></li>
      </ul>     
  </div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHyx30kgVEUwAg40pIcI?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for your simple answer...it's works for me...thanks

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fDBlyr7KtR9MPX2R?preview)

```
 <input type="text" name="kpcategory" 
      data-ng-model="kpcategory.category" value="kpcategory">

 <div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:kpcategory ">
<ul>
    <li><span>{{question.category}} , {{question.name}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Note**: I have made `data-ng-model="kpcategory.category"` in the input field